# equality check in python

Tags: python, equality

```
x=(100+1.0/3)-100
y=1.0/3
z=1+1.0/3-1
```

x, y, z clearly have the same values mathematically, but

```
print(x==y)
print(x==z)
print(y==z)
```

generate False values for all.

Is there any way to make them equal to each other in python? I'm not quite sure why they're not considered same. I'm aware that rounding off would be the cause of it, but I'm not sure why that happens in different ways for x, y, z.

Comment: You can't compare floats directly due to floating point error. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: Could also be a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.

Comment: This is to do with how computers deal with what's called [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are running into floating point errors. The output of `x`, `y`, and `z` are:

```
>>> x
0.3333333333333286
>>> y
0.3333333333333333
>>> z
0.33333333333333326
```

You can see that they are clearly not equal.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) for information about floating point errors.